# Code::Blocks error: "...project has not been built yet"

Tags: code-blocks

I'm a Lubuntu user. I installed Code::Blocks and when I ran the simple program "Hello world", this error appeared:

> It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?

What can I do?

Comment: What happens when you click "Yes"? Do you receive this error message each time you try to run it? Normally, after selecting "Yes" the program should be built and be able to run the second time. Could you paste the build log?

Answer (score 2):

It may be because you don´t have your libraries for C language installed.

Try this:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

or try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After installation, open your code blocks and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

make sure while saving the file, you gave it a *.cpp* extension. Then click on triangular button you can see on the top of the screen, which is your build and run button

Comment: How do you know the program was written in C++?

Answer (score 0):

I ran on the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

and that fixed the error...

Comment: The package [`build-essential`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential) mentioned in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903659/250300) depends on `g++`.